# Why when redirecting variable to stdin variable must be in double quotes?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

why this expression works `cat > d.txt <<< "$val"`and `cat > d.txt <<< $val` is not working? As i understand `<<<` is redirects variable value to stdin. Am i right?

Comment: It redirects the following *word* to standard input. `$val` might expand to more than one word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cat >d.txt <<<$val` will work fine as long as `$val` contains no spaces.  Otherwise, using double quotes is necessary to prevent each word within `$val` from being treated as a separate argument.

For example, if you have

```
val="a b"
cat >d.txt <<<$val
```

what the shell tries to do is

```
cat >d.txt <<<a b
```

so only the "a" is provided as input, and the "b" is just another argument to `cat`.

By using double quotes

```
val="a b"
cat >d.txt <<<"$val"
```

now the shell executes

```
cat >d.txt <<<"a b"
```

so the whole string "a b" is treated as input.